# How to add variant to existing big commerce product

Tags: bigcommerce

I have an existing product on Big Commerce.  It already has two variants.  How can I add a third variant without having to recreate the item again?  Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a new variant using this endpoint:

POST `/v3/catalog/products/{prodID}/variants`

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#/reference/catalog/variants

If you're creating the new variant separately from the base product and its existing variants, the request body will need to reference the option choices and their values by ID. (This means that the options need to already exist in the store.) Here's a sample request body:

```
{
  "sku": "New-SKU",
  "option_values": [
    {
      "id": 849,
      "option_id": 502
    },
    {
      "id": 847,
      "option_id": 504
    },
    {
      "id": 844,
      "option_id": 503
    }
  ]
}
```

To create a new option value, first do a get to product/{prodID}/options to get the option ID. Then, POST to `/v3/catalog/products/1239/options/502/values` :

```
{
      "is_default": false,
      "sort_order": 4,
      "label": "Purple"
}
```

This would add a new Purple value to the option selections.

Comment: Thank you Karen,  The particular size and color do not exist in the system yet. Can you provide a simple example of adding a new value to the options?

Comment: Sure--I'll update my answer with an example for new option value :)

Comment: Hi Karen, You were very helpful with answering my questions and I was able to create a new option and then a new variant.  Thank you so much.